# Can't center views in tableHeaderView with auto layout and storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I can't center a view that has been placed as a subview of a UITableView's tableHeaderView in a storyboard using auto layout.

In a storyboard, I have a `UITableView`. I dragged a `UIView` (the red view) to the top, released, and it created a table header view automatically. I then dragged and dropped another `UIView` (the yellow view) on top of the table header view, resized, and applied some constraints to ensure it stays centered:

[image]

When I run the app on the simulator, here's what I get:

[image]

The yellow view is obviously not centered. However, the "Filter" button at the bottom is.

I know it's tricky to get the height right using auto layout and storyboards and table header views (and you can see that the height of the red view is definitely incorrect), but at this point, I'm just trying to solve for horizontally centering my yellow view.

Am I able to set this all up in my storyboard without having to configure my constraints in code?

Comment: You have to apply constraints to the header view ___and___ the views within it

Comment: unfortunately you can't apply constraints to a headerView in a storyboard. The system doesn't let you.

Comment: Seems like the header is taking up the whole screen. Can you confirm that your UITableView has the leading,trailing,bottom,top constraints set up against its superview? Also are the "margin" check box disabled in the constaints setup popup?

Comment: Oh man, that was it! In a frenzy of trial and error, I had either forgotten to add or removed the constraints from the actual tableview. Leave an actual answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your UITableView has the leading, trailing, bottom, top constraints set up against its superview.

Answer (score 1):

Check the table header view and all sub views have Autoresize Subviews enabled:

[image: Xcode screenshot showing Autoresize Subviews checkbox]

You can also force the table to re-render the header view by re-setting it to the same view:

`[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.outletToHeaderView];`

**Update**: to resize the table header view, give give it an appropriate frame in `viewWillAppear`:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.outletToHeaderView.frame;
newFrame.size.width = self.tableView.bounds.size.width;
newFrame.size.height = 44;
[self.outletToHeaderView setFrame:newFrame];
// Then reset it to force the table view to re-render/accommodate
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.outletToHeaderView]
```

Comment: both the header (red) and subview (yellow) have `Autoresize Subviews` checked. And I tried resetting the header view like you suggested, but that didn't work.

Comment: how did the red table header view get so tall? Can you print the frame of the header view and yellow sub view. Do it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: haha, that's a good question. if you search around, there's a ton of questions about how to properly resize the height of a header view. that's my next question. however, based on a comment to my question, I just realized it's not getting centered because my actual tableview didn't have constraints applied. adding leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints solves the centering issue, but now i still have a table who's height is incorrect.

Comment: updated answer to include resetting table view header having resized it manually

Comment: any way to do it without using an explicit value like 44? It'd be great if it was just the same height as in my storyboard.

Comment: You can leave height unchanged on the updated frame - it'll stay the same as the height in storyboard unless you have any rogue constraints on the tableViewHeader itself.

Comment: that's the weird thing...none of my constraints relate to height. the size of my table header view is 88, yet in viewDidAppear, it prints out as 568, coincidentally the same size as the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In your file TableViewHeader:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yourView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prototype cell from table view, than dequeue it with reusable identifier and return it contentView. Only that's do the trick

```
var headerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.headerView = (self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeaderCell") as! UITableViewCell).contentView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return self.headerView
}
```

**upd:**
Oh sorry, my example is written in Swift. But it's easy to understand how to do the same in Obj-C

Comment: thanks for the tip, but that didn't work. at this point my headerView isn't even a subclass, just a normal UIView. in `viewForHeaderInSection:` I tried returning `self.tableHeaderView` but that had the same off-centered results.